google search consloe: ownership verification failed
I am hosting my website in github. I want to confirm the ownership in google search console (gsc).

Account: https://github.com/mavens-group
Page: https://github.com/mavens-group/mavens-group.github.io
url: https://mavens-group.github.io

So, I have done: gsc-> url prefix-> downloaded the html file and put it in my page repo (https://github.com/mavens-group/mavens-group.github.io/blob/main/google1641d8943c4b9324.html).
Now, if I am trying to verify through gsc, this is showing error:
Verification method:
HTML file
Failure reason:
Your verification file was not found in the required location.

What I am doing wrong here?
Kindly help.
I am trying to do this verification because even after a week of creating and publisshing the site, google is yet to index it.

'https://github.com/mavens-group/mavens-group.github.io/blob/main/google1641d8943c4b9324.html' is a github page that displays the file you uploaded. What google is looking for is the actual page. try the html tag verification instead.

As you have hosted on GitHub it would be better if you choose the Html TAG verification method. As it will be very easy for the Google Bots to verify
